# How to push Json and select

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make post filter in my web site. There are `checkboxes` which will do filtration posts.

If `checkbox` is not checked there will not be that user's posts in page.

When page is loaded, `checkboxes` are not checked, so that I am trying to take some posts to Json format with `checkbox id` while page is loading.

If `checkbox` is checked, post will be visible.

I have tried that code part which is below.

I am getting null length error. could you help me? Is there a different way of doing this?

```
$(":checkbox").click(function () {

    if (this.checked) {

        $.each(inspostHtml.filters, function (i, v) { 
            if (parseInt(v.id) == parseInt($(this).attr('ID')) ) {                              
               alert(v.html); return; 
            }
        });
     } // end of if(this.checked)
     else {
          alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
    var _inspostHtml ={
                 "filters":[{
                        "id" : parseInt($("input:checkbox").attr('ID')), 
                          "html" :getMessageHtml(post.title, post.message, post.ID)}
                         ]};
    inspostHtml.push(_inspostHtml);
```

**HTML**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.FilterType.Count; i++) 
{ 
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.FilterType[i].Checked, new { id = Model.FilterType[i].ID })
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FilterType[i].Text) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FilterType[i].Text)<br /> 
}
```

Comment: please add relevent html?

Comment: This is for creating checkboxes:
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.FilterType.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.FilterType[i].Checked, new { id = Model.FilterType[i].ID })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FilterType[i].Text)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FilterType[i].Text)<br />
        }

Comment: post the rendered HTML as @MuhammadUsman said. Not RAZOR code.